# I tried to find Fourier series, but incorrectly, can someone tell me where is my mistake?

Tags: fourier-series

Here is the given function: $x^2 - \pi x + \frac{\pi^2}{6}$

$$a_0 = \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}(x^2 - \pi x + \frac{\pi^2}{6})dx = \left. \frac{1}{3}x^3-\frac{\pi}{2}x^2 +\frac{\pi^2x}{6}\right|^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}=2\left(\frac{1}{3}\frac{\pi^3}{8}-\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\pi^2}{4}+\frac{\pi^3}{24}\right) = -\frac{\pi^3}{12}$$

$$› \\ a_n = \left. (x^2 - \pi x + \frac{\pi^2}{6})\cos\left(2nx\right)\right|^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{-\frac{\pi}{2}} -\frac{1}{2n} \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{-\frac{\pi}{2}} (2x-\pi)\sin (2nx) dx =\\ -2(\frac{2\pi^2}{4}-\frac{2\pi^2}{2})  - \left. \frac{1}{2n} (2x-\pi)\sin(2n x) \right|^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{-\frac{\pi}{2}} +\left. \frac{1}{2n^2}\cos (2nx)\right|^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}  =  \pi^2-\frac{1}{n^2} \\ b_n = \left. (x^2 - \pi x + \frac{\pi^2}{6})\sin\left(2nx\right)\right|^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{-\frac{\pi}{2}} +\frac{1}{2n} \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{-\frac{\pi}{2}} (2x-\pi)\cos (2nx) dx = \left. \frac{1}{2n}\left((2x-\pi) \cos(2 n x)\right)\right|^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}- \\ - \frac{1}{2n^2}\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin 2nx = \frac{1}{2n} 2\pi  \\ f(x) = -\frac{\pi^3}{24} + \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} (\pi^2-\frac{1}{n^2}) \cos (2n x) + \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{\pi}{n} \sin (2nx)$$

Another try:

$$a_0 = \frac{1}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_0 (x^2-\pi x +\frac{\pi^2}{6})dx = \frac{1}{\pi}\left[ \left.\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{\pi x^2}{2}+\frac{\pi^2 x}{6} \right|^{\pi}_0\right] = \frac{1}{\pi}\left(\frac{2\pi^3 -3\pi^3+\pi^3}{6}\right) = 0 $$

$$a_n = \frac{2}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_0 \left(x^2-\pi x +\frac{\pi^2}{6}\right)\cos \left(\frac{2\pi n x}{\pi}\right)dx = \frac{2}{\pi} \left. \left(\frac{1}{2n}\left(x^2-\pi x  +\frac{\pi^2}{6}\right)\sin(2nx)\right|^{\pi}_0 - \\ -\int^{\pi}_0 \left(2x-\pi)\cos(2nx)\right)dx\right) = \frac{\pi}{6 n}\sin(2\pi n) - \left(\frac{2}{\pi} \left.\left(\frac{1}{2n}(2x-\pi)\sin(2nx)\right|^{\pi}_0 -\int^{\pi}_0 2\cos(2nx)dx\right)\right)=\\ = \frac{\pi}{6n}\sin(2\pi n)-\frac{1}{n}\sin(2\pi n) +\frac{2}{\pi n}\sin(2\pi n) = \sin(2\pi n)\left(\frac{\pi}{6n}-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{2}{\pi n}\right) = \sin(2\pi n)\frac{6+\pi^2}{6\pi n}$$

And for some reason $b_n$ does not equal 0 according to my calculations:

$$b_n = \frac{2}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_0 \left(x^2-\pi x+\frac{\pi^2}{6}\right) \left. \sin(2n x) dx = -\frac{1}{\pi n}\left(x^2 - \pi x + \frac{\pi^2}{6}\right)\cos(2nx)\right|^{\pi}_{0} -\frac{2}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_{0}(2x-\pi)\sin(2nx)dx = \\ = -\frac{\pi}{6n} + \left. \frac{1}{\pi n}(2x-\pi)\cos(2nx) \right|^{\pi}_0 + \frac{4}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_0\sin(2nx) dx = \left. \frac{6-\pi}{6n} -\frac{2}{\pi n} \cos(2nx) \right|^{\pi}_0 = \frac{6\pi - \pi^2-12}{6\pi n }$$

Comment: It seems to me the periodic function is defined in $[0,\pi]$ since $f(0)=f(\pi)$. While $f$ is discontinuous in $\pm\pi/2$. So you are not integrating the right  function here, you need to shift it.

Comment: @zwim Ok, it the exercise it is given that $x \in [0, \pi]$ (although I don't know why this is). Should I integrate the function over this interval or by shifting you mean something else?

Comment: If $f(x+T)=f(x)$ then $\int_a^b f(t)dt=\int_{a+T}^{b+T}f(t)dt$ so you can do either integrate $f(x)$ on $[0,\pi]$ or integrate $f(x+\pi/2)$ on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. Also don't forget to divide your coefficients by $T$.

Comment: @zwin Here I tried again to integrate over $[0;\pi]$, but already two coefficients are equal to zero, so I assume something's incorrect.

Comment: Since function is symmetric relatively to $\pi/2$ we have $b_n=0$, $a_0=0$ is ok, but I find $a_n=1/n^2$. I can see some sign errors, for instance $\int fg'=fg-\int f'g$ you have $g'=\cos$ so $g=\sin$ but you wrote $-\sin$.

Comment: Of course you need to include in the question the information that you want the Fourier series on $[0,\pi]$.  And whether you want the cosine series or the sine series.

Comment: How about $f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}\cos(2kx)$.

Comment: @zwin I went through my third attempt of integration and I didn't see an error, but the result is different.

Comment: @zwim I also calculated $b_n$, but it doesn't equal 0 in my computations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{align}\frac {\pi}2a_n 
&= \int_0^{\pi} f(x)\cos(2nx)\mathop{dx} = \overbrace{\bigg[f(x)\frac {\sin(2nx)}{2n}\bigg]_0^\pi}^{=0} - \int_0^{\pi} f'(x)\frac {\sin(2nx)}{2n}\mathop{dx} \\\\
&= -\bigg[f'(x)\frac {-\cos(2nx)}{4n^2}\bigg]_0^{\pi}+\overbrace{\int_0^{\pi}\underbrace{f''(x)}_{=2}\frac {-\cos(2nx)}{4n^2}\mathop{dx}}^{=0}\\\\
&=\frac 1{4n^2}\bigg[f'(\pi)-f'(0)\bigg]=\frac 1{4n^2}\bigg[(2\pi-\pi)-(2\times 0-\pi)\bigg]=\dfrac{\pi}{2n^2}\end{align}$

---

$\begin{align}\frac {\pi}2b_n 
&= \int_0^{\pi} f(x)\sin(2nx)\mathop{dx} = \overbrace{\bigg[f(x)\frac {-\cos(2nx)}{2n}\bigg]_0^\pi}^{=0} - \int_0^{\pi} f'(x)\frac {-\cos(2nx)}{2n}\mathop{dx} \\\\
&= \overbrace{\bigg[f'(x)\frac {\sin(2nx)}{4n^2}\bigg]_0^{\pi}}^{=0}-\overbrace{\int_0^{\pi}\underbrace{f''(x)}_{=2}\frac {\sin(2nx)}{4n^2}\mathop{dx}}^{=0}=0\\\\
\end{align}$

Thus we get $a_n=\dfrac 1{n^2}$ for $n\ge 1$ and $b_n=0$ as expected by symmetry.

Notice that most of the square brackets and integrals are zero because $\cos(2nx)$ and $\sin(2nx)$ are vanishing on $[0,\pi]$ so we do not need to carry full calculation,that is why I used $f$ instead of developping it.

But I could also have written things like $\bigg[(\text{stuff})\times\sin(2nx)\bigg]_0^{\pi}=0$ with even less details...

You made a lot of sign errors, combined to swaps of $\cos$ instead of $\sin$ and vice-versa (the reason is integration by parts is $\int uv'=[uv]-\int u'v$ but you used $-\int u'v'$).

You need to pay a bit more attention when performing your calculations.

**Anyway big kudos for actually performing the work after my hints, very few posters do that.**